Issue with Re-rendering of Horizontal ScrollView Inside Vertical ScrollView in SwiftUI
I am encountering an issue with re-rendering of a horizontal ScrollView inside a vertical ScrollView in SwiftUI. The vertical ScrollView contains multiple horizontal ScrollViews, each displaying a list of items horizontally. However, whenever I scroll vertically, the horizontal ScrollViews are re-rendered, causing performance issues.
I have added a random color to the Rectangle to check if it's being re-rendered. However, due to the re-rendering, the scroll state is not being maintained.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { _ in
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { _ in
                                Rectangle()
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.debug)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .border(Color.blue)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public extension ShapeStyle where Self == Color {
    static var debug: Color {
        Color(red: .random(in: 0...1), green: .random(in: 0...1), blue: .random(in: 0...1))
    }
}

If you run this code, observe closely while scrolling; you'll notice that the color of the rectangle changes continuously.

I think the behavior is expected from lazy container: please read about LazyVStack

Yup because of that I feel the performance issue while scrolling. Also horizontal scroll state is not getting maitaining
